# What drugs was Moshe on?

Tags: purim-torah-in-jest

[Shmot 30:34](http://www.mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0230.htm#34):

> ויאמר יהוה אל-משה קח-לך סמים...
>
> Hashem said to Moshe, take drugs...

What was Moshe on? And where do we see examples of this?

---

## This question is [Purim Torah](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purim_Torah) and is not intended to be taken completely seriously. See the [Purim Torah policy](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/797/).

Comment: Hopefully permissible ones :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When Moshe was on Har Sinai receiving the torah he was high (up), so he must have had the drugs then.

Before *matan torah* he was on Har Sinai once before, talking to a burning bush.  But it wasn't much of a bush -- a [lowly thing](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/66856/472), according to R' Eliezer in *Sh'mot Rabbah*, barely a bush at all.

More like a weed, really.

While *poskim* frown on weed because of the harm it does to us, there is [room for leniency](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/12808/472) if it's actually good for you.  Weed provided by God Himself, presented aflame to suggest smoking, is surely ok.

So the drug Moshe used was *cannabis*.

Comment: Related: http://youtu.be/qr-Bn_wT07c

Comment: Was Moshe that high up? http://halakhah.com/pdf/moed/Sukkah.pdf#page=10

Comment: @DoubleAA he was higher than the rest of b'nei Yisrael.  Whether he was higher than a kite is unknown.

Answer (score 1):

One drug that we know he took was [RNA / DNA](http://www.webmd.com/vitamins-supplements/ingredientmono-804-rna%20and%20dna.aspx?activeingredientid=804&activeingredientname=rna%20and%20dna) complex. Because Moses was about 80 years old, and we know that he fasted for about 120 days during approx. his first year leading the people, G-d was fearful that he would lose protein, so G-d tells him:

Exodus 30:34:

> וַיֹּאמֶר֩ יְהוָ֨ה אֶל־מֹשֶׁ֜ה קַח־לְךָ֣ סַמִּ֗ים ... וְחֶלְבְּנָ֔ה
>
> Take drugs - protein

DNA & RNA are the main composites of protein.

Comment: RNA and DNA are nucleic acids, not amino acids.